# How to remove CR in columns in Oracle custom tables

Tags: line, carriage-return

I am exporting thousands of lines out of some custom Oracle tables bit am finding many records with an erroneous CR at the end of the data column which then exports it as a new line. This can be seen clearly when I review it in notepad++.
I would therefore like to update my custom table removing the end of line indicator (CR) so that when I export the records it does not split into a nee line for 1 record.
How can I achieve this?

I have not tried anything as I don't know how to identify these records without manually reviewing thousands of records and then doing an update script which will be most cumbersome.

I am expecting to be able to identify the offending records and to be able to remove the (CR) carriage return character in the columns.